# actions on google program get unhealthy

Tags: actions-on-google

For the last 2 weeks I get frequent alert that my google assistant program becomes unhealthy, then become healthy again after 1/2 hour or one hour. Looks to me that this is due to Google hosting since I am not doing any correction action and the logs are not showing anything special. Anybody experiencing the same thing ?
Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There have been intermittent reports of this issue in [the Google Assistant developers Slack](http://googleslack.com/). Your best bet may be to reach out to support.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Issue is I don't have a premium contract and have no way to contact support other than stackoverflow ....

Comment: You don't need an Enterprise contract to use [email support](https://dialogflow.com/support): support@dialogflow.com